# getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection/ setComposingText on inactive InputConnection/ getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection

Tags: android, android-emulator

this is my code for connect android app to external database contained in a pc server!! My app work very well in the emulator of eclipse,but when i use the app in my samsung galaxy s2 doesn't work!! When i try to write in EditText logCat said:

`05-08 21:54:25.800: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(876): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
05-08 21:54:25.805: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(876): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
05-08 21:54:25.805: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(876): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection`

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
 EditText username1;
 EditText password1;
 TextView status;
 ResultSet rs;

//private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2:3306/tesina";
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.10:3306/tesina";
private static final String user = "root";
private static final String pass = "";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    username1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
    password1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);

    //status =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);
    Button btnLogin=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
     btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View view) {


             new Connessione().execute();

          }
     });
 }

 private class Connessione extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... String) {
                String us = username1.getText().toString();




                try {

                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                   rs = (ResultSet) stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM prova WHERE nome='"+us+"'");
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }   
                return null;
                }
           protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

            }


            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            String p = password1.getText().toString();
               try {

                if(rs.next())
                   {  
                       String dbpass = rs.getString(2);
                       if(dbpass.equals(p))
                       {

                           Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,classi.class);
                           i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                           startActivity(i);
                          finish();

                       }
                   else
                   {

                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "errore: password non inserita correttamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                   }
                  }
                   else
                   {
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "errore:username non trovato", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                   }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "applicazione non collegata al database della scuola", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            }
            }
```

}

`

Comment: THose messages aren't the problem.  It means that the keyboard is trying to see what text is selected, but the input connection is inactive (probably hasn't finished initializing).  Its not a problem.

Comment: Is your device on wifi, and is the router set up so that traffic from the wifi network can be passed through to your PC?  That address won't work through the cellular network, it isn't an outside IP.

Comment: yes my samsung is on wifi, but i don't know if my router is set up so that the traffic from the wifi network can be passed through my pc!! how can i set up the router??

Comment: and this url 'private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.10:3306/tesina";' is wrong??